# Modify existing schema for SonataPageBundle: page__site doesn't exist

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-sonata

After finally(!) adding SonataPageBundle to an existing app I get when going to the dev environment

> SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table
>   'volunteer.page__site' doesn't exist

on running `php app/console sonata:page:create-site`.  Nowhere in the documentation for the PageBundle is there any mention of how to create the schema.

If I do `doctrine:schema:create --dump-sql` to see what's what I get

> [Doctrine\DBAL\DBALException]
>   Unknown column type "json" requested...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A search in the installed PageBundle directory (i.e., not at the Sonata-Project website) revealed the instruction to modify `app/config/config.yml` with

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        ...
        types:
            json: Sonata\Doctrine\Types\JsonType
```

With this addition the schema could then be updated and a site created.

If my sanity holds I'll fork the documentation to have it match a known good procedure.